# Buffers comand to show full path and filename

Tags: buffers

Using `:buffers` results

```
:buffers
  1 %a   "my-jspage.md"                 line 11
```

Are there any options so `:buffers` will list full path and filename? E.g.:

```
:buffers
  1 %a   "d:\projects\self-org\my-jspage.md"                 line 11
```

I'm on windows Vim 7.4-656. I'm aware of `:ls` :)

Comment: I find it really annoying that the `:buffers` list shows the current file without the path, even though all other files in the list are shown with the path. This is like the worst of both worlds. It may be a feature, but it's not a good feature. I display full path in the statusline which helps somewhat: `set statusline+=%-.80F " filepath left align max length 80 "`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim reduces the filespec of the open buffers to a shorter, relative representation. (That's a feature, not a bug.) You can work around that behavior by switching the current working directory (temporarily) to the file system root / (on Windows:) to a drive not currently used:

```
:cd C:/ | buffers | cd -
```

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any options so `:buffers` will list full path and filename?

No, but you can use `fnamemodify()` to find out the full path:

```
:echo fnamemodify(bufname(1), ':p')
```

Comment: And to obtain the complete list, you have this oneliner `echo join(map(filter(copy(range(1, bufnr('$'))), 'buflisted(v:val)'), '"  ".fnamemodify(bufname(v:val), ":p")'), "\n")`. However, if you want to display the other information (displayed by `:buffer`), prefer a loop to build the _indicators_ string.